# Where are the default ASP.Net MVC editor template for Object class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object, mvc-editor-templates

Where can I found the default editor templates for Object class? (ASP.Net MVC 5);

I would like to create a new template on my project View/Shared/EditorTemplates folder based on the default one.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a decompiler like ILSpy and check the MVC assembly.... http://ilspy.net/

Comment: You can use my project http://formfactory.apphb.com/ instead of EditorTemplates - the view templates are very easy to manipulate.